# WPF Is it possible to host a control from one thread in another?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0

I have a WPF app which has main window started in 'default' UI thread. I also have several other windows each has its own UI thread (by calling `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()`)

However for a specific reason I would like to have these windows as user controls hosted in the main window.

Is it possible (to have a control which was created in one thread to be hosted in a window created in another thread) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the answer is no based on one of the arguments for not using DependencyObject as the base of your ViewModels being threading issues.

[KenB on the subject](http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/view-models-pocos-versus.html)

And I quote:

> A DependencyObject has thread affinity - it can only be accessed on the thread on which it was created.

Comment: yeah. that was my hope - by hosting - I meant simply to hold a visual tree but do not access it... (the main window is a pot and the other thread control is a tree - i just wanted to stick one into another :))